# Mantener item de menu seleccionado con otro color

Tags: html

Buenas me pueden ayudar, tengo el siguiente menu en una master page:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
<Items>
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Catalogo.aspx" Text="HOME"/>
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Catalogo.aspx" Text="CATALOGO DE PRODUCTOS"/>
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/listacomprados.aspx" Text="DETALLE DE COMPRA"/>
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="ACERCA DE"/>
<asp:MenuItem Text="CERRAR SESION"/>
<asp:MenuItem Text="PRUEBA" />

</Items>
```

Quiero que al seleccionar un `item` por ejemplo "PRUEBA" este me lleva a otra pagina, pero quiero que el `item` "PRUEBA" se mantenga con otro color en el background. Saludos y gracias.

Si miran esta misma pagina al seleccionar el `item` "Formular una pregunta" se mantiene con otro color el `item`. Es exactamente lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Cuando haces click en "Formular pregunta" realmente no es que se mantenga el color del botón al cambiar de página, sino que la nueva página carga y verifica cuales botones deberían de cambiar el color de background. Es decir que en la nueva página al cargar debe comprobar si le establece un background al item o no.

Comment: Por favor @Yehudy indica en las etiquetas o en la publicación el lenguaje de programación utilizado. Tal vez por CodeBehind se te pueda ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Estoy en ASP.NET visual basic. Ya he buscado de todo ya nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que elimines las propiedades `EnableViewState` y `IncludeStyleBlock` y agregues `StaticSelectedStyle` en el menú, quedando de esta forma tu aspx:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="Red" />
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Catalogo.aspx"  Text="HOME"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Catalogo.aspx" Text="CATALOGO DE PRODUCTOS"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/listacomprados.aspx" Text="DETALLE DE COMPRA"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="ACERCA DE"/>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="CERRAR SESION"/>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="PRUEBA"  />

        <%--<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/inicio.aspx" Text="CERRAR SESION"/>--%>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Y además, agregas el siguiente código en el `Page_Load` del `Visual Basic`:

```
Try
    For Each m As MenuItem In NavigationMenu.Items
        Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath + ".aspx"
        Dim words As String() = m.NavigateUrl.Split(New Char() {"/"c})
        Dim words2 As String() = path.Split(New Char() {"/"c})

        If words(1).ToString().Equals(words2(1).ToString()) Then
            m.Selected = True
        End If
    Next
Catch
End Try
```

Comment: Excelente ya me funcionó. Muchas gracias